# Resetting Backbone collection with new models doesn't override previous models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to make a bulk reset on a Backbone collection each time I receive new data, what I expect to happen is that every time I make the reset all current models are emptied and new data reset on top but what I find is that the new data just gets added as new models alongside the previous models. Can anyone advise what I need to do to achieve this?

**JS**

```
const OrderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse(response) {
        response.name = `+${response.name}`;
        console.log(response.name);
        return response;
    }
});

const OrdersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: OrderModel,

    initialize() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.trigger('snapshot', data);
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.trigger('snapshot', data);
        }, 2000);

        this.listenTo(this, 'snapshot', this.setCollection, this);
    },

    setCollection(response) {
        this.reset(response, {parse: true});
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/cpbcx7nt/

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your problem. Each time your collection is reset, the length is always 3.

Comment: If you check the fiddle each time the collection is reset an additional 3 models are added. The problem that I'm running into is the first set of model data gets set, parse gets run on each model to add a + to name, next set of data gets set and the models run parse again but this time 2 ++ get added and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpbcx7nt/3/

There are 2 problems occurring.

First problem is that while you're resetting the collection, you are not resetting the html. You need to clear the previous 3 list items before adding them again.

Like so:

```
renderRows() {
    this.$el.empty()
    this.collection.each(this.renderRow, this);
},
```

Second problem is with this piece of code

```
const OrderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse(response) {
        response.name = `+${response.name}`;
        return response;
    }
});
```

The parameter `response` references an object inside the `data` array. When you change the `name` property of `response`, you are also changing the referenced object inside `data`. You see an extra "+" the second time parse is called because you mutated `data` in the first parse.

I cloned the object to prevent this accidental overwrite.

```
const OrderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse(response) {
      var model = _.clone(response);
      model.name = `+${response.name}`;
        return model;
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer, I've always just directly updated the data variable in parse but only encountering this problem now with this type of implementation. Will try this in my main project and see if problem is resolved! Thanks